# Copy Warning Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aware of the view vs. copy issue and the reason for the warning that Pandas displays. This has made me more careful to use,loc, .ix, etc rather than chained indexing.

However I'm generating warnings when I'm convinced I shouldn't be. I have a dataframe "df" containing my data and I have a function:

```
def my_func(df):
    df['new_channel'] = df.channel.diff()
    return df
```

If I run this function I get no warnings. However if I then define a new dataframe from my original one like this:

```
df2 = df.ix[df.channel==val,:]
```

Calling the function:

```
my_func(df2)
```

Then generates copy warnings. But my understanding is that I'm not using any chained indexing in my function and I haven't used chained indexing to create the second dataframe.

Is this a false positive - i.e. I can just turn the warning off and carry on. Or have I missed something more fundamental that could bite me in the future?

Ben

Comment: I am pretty sure the way they implemented this warning is very liberal, and this case is a false positive. But if you want to make sure, it would be useful if you tried to replicate it in a minimal example which we could copy-paste and run.

Comment: The function is more involved than the generic example, and I get no error if I run the whole thing as a script with no def(): at the top. So I suspect (hope?) you're right.

Comment: If you look at it as a combined step, you are doing `df.ix[df.channel==val,:]['new_channel'] = ...`, which is chained indexing. That does not necessarily mean it won't work, but it can explain the generation of the warning. If you want to avoid it, and if you don't want that the original `df` is modified if you modify `df2`, you can add a `.copy()` when subsetting `df`: `df2 = df.ix[df.channel==val,:].copy()`

Comment: Joris - thanks for the reply. Very clear.

Comment: Interestingly, after resetting the index by `df2 = df.ix[df.channel==val,:].reindex()`, adding a new column does not give the warning.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's trivial to reset the index, so an easy fix.